# Openmp - for's inside for's

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize a "for" with openmp.
However the result, *parallel code vs nonparallel*, is different. I believe that it is related with the definition of the *sum* variable outside of the loop, but I don't know how to solve the problem.

What I want is to parallelize the first "for" loop.

Edit: 1

Here is the simplest example I could find.

```
//g++ -o test2 test2.cpp -fopenmp
//
//

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double f(double i, double j)
{
return i + j;
}

int main()
{
const int size = 256;
double sum = 0;

//will use openmp
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j=j+1)
    {
        if(i != j)
        {
            sum = sum + f(i,j);
        }
    }

}

cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;


//not using openmp
sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j=j+1)
    {
        if(i != j)
        {
            sum = sum + f(i,j);
        }
    }

}

cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;  

}
```

Comment: I don't think you showed us the part of your code that contains the bug.  One of your "do things" omitted sections must do something that misuses static data and/or depends on "earlier" iterations of the parallel loop.

Comment: It is hard to distinguish what is a bug vs. what only looks like a bug because you omitted something important.  But `dist` most clearly and maybe all the other variables at that level, look like bugs.  If constant during the loop then you missed the initialization of `dist`.  If not constant during the loop, then most likely a bug in making the loop parallel.

Comment: Ok, I gonna repost the question with a more "clear" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the access to `sum` being performed by several threads. I.e. when the first thread reaches

```
sum=sum+f(i,j);
```

it grabs `sum`, does the calculations, writes the result to `sum`. When another thread in the meantime arrived at that line, it grabs the old value of `sum` and dumps its result, overwriting the first threads results.

A solution would be to set

```
double increment=f(i,j);
#pragma omp critical
sum+=increment;
```

Also note that your code's results are not predictable and change when you run it several times.

Comment: This answer correctly identifies the problem, a *data race* on `sum`.  But a better solution than wrapping updates to `sum` in a `critical` section would be to use OpenMP's `reduction` capabilities.  I don't have the time to write such an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, it finally works.

The following code is a working code with Christoph Solution.

```
//g++ -o test2 test2.cpp -fopenmp

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double f(double i, double j)
{
    return i + j;
}

int main()
{
  const int size = 256;

  double sum = 0;

//will use openmp
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j=j+1)
    {
        if(i != j)
        {
            double increment = f(i,j);
            #pragma omp critical
            sum = sum + increment;
        }
    }

}

cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;


//not using openmp
sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j=j+1)
    {
        if(i != j)
        {
            sum = sum + f(i,j);
        }
    }

}

cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;  

 }
```

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if you feel it solves your problem. Also keep in mind the comment on it. OpenMP offers different solutions for such problems and you may wish to familiarize yourself with them before addressing real life problems.